# How to have the result of a select query being inserted as a value of an attribute in an insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to have a the result of a select query inserted in an insert statement, the code is:

```
INSERT INTO entry (
        event_id,
        entry_no, 
        entry_starttime, 
        entry_finishtime,
        comp_no,
        team_id,
        char_id
    ) VALUES ( 
        **SELECT event_id FROM event WHERE carn_date = to_date((SELECT carn_date FROM carnival WHERE carn_name = 'RM Autumn Series Caulfield 2022'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') and eventtype_code = '21K',**
        1,
        TO_DATE('08:31:44', 'HH24:MI:SS'),
        TO_DATE('09:02:44', 'HH24:MI:SS'),
        6,
        NULL, 
        NULL
    );
```

I am trying to have the result of `SELECT event_id FROM event WHERE carn_date = to_date((SELECT carn_date FROM carnival WHERE carn_name = 'RM Autumn Series Caulfield 2022'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') and eventtype_code = '21K'` being inserted as the value of `event_id` but it is giving me syntax error saying that 'missing expression'.

But when I run the select statement individually it perfectly gives out the desired result. Which is 14.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO entry (
  event_id,
  entry_no, 
  entry_starttime, 
  entry_finishtime,
  comp_no,
  team_id,
  char_id
)
SELECT event_id,
       1,
       TRUNC(carn_date) + INTERVAL '08:31:44' HOUR TO SECOND,
       TRUNC(carn_date) + INTERVAL '09:02:44' HOUR TO SECOND,
       6,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   event
WHERE  eventtype_code = '21K'
AND    carn_date = (SELECT carn_date
                    FROM   carnival
                    WHERE carn_name = 'RM Autumn Series Caulfield 2022');
```

---

You can also wrap your nested `SELECT` in `()` brackets; however, you will then get the default date components for year, month and day (which will be the first day of the current month and year) for the `entry_starttime` and `entry_finishtime` columns when you probably do not want that and instead want them to match the date of the carnival (which the first query does).

```sql
INSERT INTO entry (
  event_id,
  entry_no, 
  entry_starttime, 
  entry_finishtime,
  comp_no,
  team_id,
  char_id
) VALUES ( 
  ( SELECT event_id
    FROM   event
    WHERE  carn_date = ( SELECT carn_date
                         FROM   carnival
                         WHERE  carn_name = 'RM Autumn Series Caulfield 2022')
    AND    eventtype_code = '21K' ),
  1,
  TO_DATE('08:31:44', 'HH24:MI:SS'),
  TO_DATE('09:02:44', 'HH24:MI:SS'),
  6,
  NULL, 
  NULL
);
```

*Note: Never use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE`. If you want to truncate the time component of a `DATE` back to midnight then then use the `TRUNC` function rather than relying on an implicit cast to a string and then back to a date.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=196709dd0515e62866290dcb0bf67e84)*

Comment: Thank you sir, I get it now. If you don't mind helping me out again please have a look at my newest thread.